# Can I change row in an ListView.Datasource individually in React-native?

Tags: react-native

I want to know whether I can change a row in an ListView.Datasource object individually in React-native? How to access some specific row individually?

I think below code will help you understand what my question is! Please see it!

(Please Consider: I guessed accessing row in a DataSource as: myDataSource[4])

Below is the code I tried:

```
class UnderstandDataSource extends Component {
  // Initialize the hardcoded data
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
        'row 0', 'row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3', 'row 4', 'row 5', 'row 6', 'row 7'
      ])
    };
    this.state.dataSource[4] = ('New row 3'); // I gussed accessing data in an D.S. as dataSource[4]
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 22}}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually change the data, then you should reset the entire datasource with the new data.

If this is just for display purpose like in your example, then you should make use of renderRow to display different Views based on the row index.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal, Text, TextInput, TouchableHighlight, View, ListView } from 'react-native';

export default class ModalExample extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
   this.state = {
     dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
       'row 0', 'row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3', 'row 4', 'row 5', 'row 6', 'row 7'
     ])
   };
  //  this.state.dataSource[4] = ('New row 3'); // I gussed accessing data in an D.S. as dataSource[4]
 }
 render() {
   return (
     <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 22}}>
       <ListView
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
         renderRow={(rowData, section, row) => {
           if (row == 3) {
             return (
               <Text>New Row 3</Text>
             )
           } else {
             return (
               <Text>{rowData}</Text>
             )
           }
         }}
       />
     </View>
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: So, what is the use of rowHasChanged method if an individual row cannot be alter?

Comment: rowHasChanged method determine if a changed row needs re-rendering. The data in the datasource is immutable and you cannot change it directly. Use cloneWithRows to update the data in the data source.

Comment: What does it mean by 'changed row' if rows cannot be alter individually?

Comment: When you pass the new dataset, all rows are not re-rendered. Only the changed ones are. rowHasChanged is used to check if there is a change or not. So, effectively your are only changing individual rows, but you will still have to pass the full array as the items in datasource are immutable.

You can read more here - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listviewdatasource.html